# What's the difference in meaning between "emigrate" and "immigrate"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the difference between *emigrate* and *immigrate?* They seem to have the same definitions in the dictionary but they are antonyms...

Comment: Related: [Emigrant and immigrant](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/emigrant-and-immigrant).

Comment: @JFW: Not to be pushy, but in case you forgot about this question: there's a good answer here, and you haven't yet accepted.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Sorry! Fixed the problem now. :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The difference is fairly subtle

- To *Emigrate* is to leave one country to settle in another. (The focus is on the original country)
- To *Immigrate* is to come to a new country to live. (The focus is on the new country)

So if I were born in Ireland, and then migrated to the US, all of the following would be true and grammatical:

> I emigrated from Ireland.
>
> I immigrated to the US.

(Now the tricky bits)

> I emigrated from Ireland to the US.  (This focuses on the leaving bit)
>
> I immigrated to the US from Ireland. (This focuses on the arriving bit)

And finally, relatives in Ireland might say:

> Dusty emigrated to the US last year. (from their perspective, I left)

While new friends in the US:

> Dusty immigrated to the US last year. (from their perspective, I arrived)

Comment: I wouldn't describe the difference between emigrate and immigrate as "fairly subtle". One is coming and the other is going. Yes, it's motion, but direction is critical. You provided great examples though.

Comment: totally awesome and an easy , simple to understand solution. great going, please keep it up

Comment: It's not obvious to me why your new friends would bother saying *to the US* at all. In my understanding people wouldn't normally use the word unless they were *in the country you emigrated to*, so it's a pretty pointless addition to the verbiage. There are plenty of instances of [immigrated from](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=emigrated+from%2Cemigrated+to%2Cimmigrated+from%2Cimmigrated+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), and they don't bother saying where you've ended up. I admit it - I just don't like the word. It makes a pointless distinction.

Answer (score 16):

To **emigrate** is to leave here and move to another country.

To **immigrate** is to leave another country and move to here.

Answer (score 14):

The "e" in emigrate is short for "ex", which means "out". You see it in words like exit (to leave), expire (out of breath >> out of time >> death), exterminate (to drive out).

The "im" in immigrate is a variant of "in", which means in. You see it in words like internal (inside), insinuate (to curve in), input (that which is put in).

This "in" should not be confused with the other "in" which means "not", used in such words as indiscriminate, incapable, and insatiable.

So, to emigrate means to exit a location. To immigrate means to come into a location.

Comment: Glad you wrote this, since this is how I remember 'immigrate' and 'emigrate'. I'll add that the source language for the "in-" prefix is Latin, and both Latin and Greek supply the meaning for the  "ex-" prefix.  (Corrections welcome if there is a Gk. source for "in-" as well, etc..)

Comment: Similarly, egress and ingress.

Comment: @Jay, you couldn't have given a better example. Thanks!

Comment: I like this answer!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Emigrate means leaving a country, immigrate means entering a country. Like "exhale" versus "inhale".

Answer (score 4):

The NOAD contains the following note about *emigrate*.

> To emigrate is to leave a country, especially one's own, intending to remain away. To immigrate is to enter a country, intending to remain there: *my aunt emigrated from Poland and immigrated to Canada*.

The OED reports that *immigrate* is chiefly North American.

Comment: If __immigrate__ is chiefly NA, what do people say elsewhere for 'to move to here (from another country)'?

Comment: @Mitch: mostly *move here*.

Answer (score 3):

Immigration and emigration have to do with humans migrating between two countries. The use depends on which country we are referring to.

With respect to the US, people who leave the country are emigrants. People who move here are immigrants.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, as an Indian ex-pat living and working in the UK:

If you're white-skinned and you move to another country you're said to have *emigrated*. If you're not white-skinned and you move to another country you're an *immigrant*.

Comment: Five and a half years later I notice a newspaper article about this: https://www.theguardian.com/global-development-professionals-network/2015/mar/13/white-people-expats-immigrants-migration

Answer (score 2):

Emigration & immigration are almost  equal to product movement internationally:

Export: leaving this country and go to another country — emigration

Import: Leaving another country & arriving in to this country — immigration