# difference between emigrate, immigrate, and migrate?

Tags: meaning, differences, meaning-in-context

what is the difference between emigrate, immigrate, and migrate? I am pretty much confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference in meaning between "emigrate" and "immigrate"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-emigrate-and-immigrate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emigrate is to leave a country for a long time, or permanently.

Immigrate is to enter a country to live there for a long time, or permanently.

Migrate is to move from one place to another, generally to live in the new place for a while.  For example birds migrate south for the winter, or migrant workers travel around settling temporarily in different places where there are jobs to be had.

See also [this topic on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-emigrate-and-immigrate?rq=1)

Comment: If there is a previous answer, please don't submit a duplicate on a current thread.