# Immigrants or Emigrants?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Emigrant” vs. “immigrant”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5734/emigrant-vs-immigrant)
> [What's the difference in meaning between “emigrate” and “immigrate”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/whats-the-difference-in-meaning-between-emigrate-and-immigrate)

I understand the immigrants refers to people coming into a country, and emigrants refers to those leaving, such as here:

> The immigrants flooded into the United States.
>
> The emigrants gather their meager belongings before boarding the ship in Liverpool.

Which word might I use in the following sentence:

> The ____________ came from the Germany to the US.

Would I simply use whichever word I had used before (if it was one of more sentences) to avoid confusion?

Comment: -1 Question does not show research effort: where did you look before you posted your question?

Comment: You know, `/ˈɪmɪgrənt/` and `/ˈɛmɪgrənt/` are not homophones, so why does this have the [tag:homophones] tag?

Comment: @tchrist I wondered that (perhaps we should edit the tag out). However some other comments are a little unfair, I think. The OP *knows* the difference between the two words, but not which one to use when referring to *both* departure point *and* destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the verb *came* so you are speaking from the travellers' arrival point. That means that they are immigrants. However you may need to re-arrange the sentence in order that "immigrants" is close to "came to":

> The immigrants came to the US from Germany.

Emigrants move from a place, as you noted.

> The emigrants went from Germany to the US.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to avoid being caught in that trap and write *migrants*.

Comment: I know I’m wrong in this, but I always think of migrants as periodic, going back and forth, like migrating swallows or migrant workers.  I don’t think of them as permanent fixtures, but ones that oscillate periodically.

Comment: @tchrist  Yah, I thought of that while I was putting it down. *Migrant workers* (who'd really be better described as "nomadic")  is probably to blame, because that's probably the only place most people encounter the word; in an academic context *migrant* would be perfectly acceptable.  It depends really on where OP is going to use whatever term he settles on.

Answer (score 0):

You would use *immigrant*.

An *immigrant* is an ***in***-migrant, while an *emigrant* is an ***out***-migrant.

Since you are using “came from”, the perspective is an in-bound one and so demands *immigrant*.  An example of the other point of view would be “emigrants who left bound for a new land”.